# How to change the permissions to be allowed to change notifications subscriptions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On our Visual Studio Team Services there is some default setup, that everyone in the "Project Collection Valid Users" get an email notification each time a queued build completes or fails.

I would like to be able to change this on my non super-admin account, but what permissions in the security tab is related to this permission?

Below is a screenshot of the not so descriptive error, that I get, when I try to set up a new subscription.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [alert permissions are documented here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#alert-permissions). (Notifications have recently been renamed from alert).

> **Alert permissions**
>
> There are no UI permissions associated with managing email notifications or alerts. Instead, they can be managed using the TFSSecurity command line tool.
>
> By default:
>
> - Members of the team project level Contributors group can subscribe to alerts for themselves.
> - Members of the Project Collection Administrators group, or users who have the Edit collection-level information can set alerts in that collection for others or for a team.
> - Members of the Project Administrators group, or users who have the Edit project-level information can set alerts in that team project for others or for a team.

And:

> **Team administrator role**
>
> For each team that you add, you can assign one or more team members as administrators. The team admin role isn't a group with a set of defined permissions. Instead, the team admin role is tasked with managing the following team assets.
>
> *Create and manage team alerts*
>
> Can add and modify alerts so that the team can receive email notifications as changes occur to work items, code reviews, source control files, and builds. For details, see Manage team alerts.
>
> There is no UI associated with managing alert permissions. Instead, you can use TFSSecurity to manage alerts in TFS.

Comment: Thnx. That explains why we couldnt find the specific permission. We ended up just going crazy on adding all kinds of roles and permissions further up, and then at some point i had the rights to change the build notifications. I can't tell which one that did the trick, but we just needed it to work :)